# Queue of transitions in d3.js; one by one

Tags: recursion, d3.js, transition

I've tried to make chained transitions in d3.js. For this I define a set of transitions in an array and (try) make a function to call recursively them using `.each("end", function())`, to start a transition when the previous is finish, but I don't have results yet.

List of actions

```
    animations = [  function(){  console.log(1); return circle.transition().duration(2e3).attr("cy", Math.random()*300); } ,
                    function(){  console.log(2); return rect.transition().duration(3e3).attr("fill", "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16)); },
                    function(){  console.log(3); return circle.transition().duration(1e3).attr("r", Math.random()*500); },
                    function(){  console.log(4); return circle.transition().duration(2e3).style("fill", "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16)); },
                    function(){  console.log(5); return circle.transition().duration(1e3).attr("cx", Math.random()*500); }]
```

The recursive function

```
    function animate(index){
        if(index < animations.length - 1){
            index = index + 1
            return animations[index]().each("end", animate(index))
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
```

The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbkunst/nGtbT/), [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1125997) is an example using a recusive function.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there!

Instead of

```
return animations[index]().each("end", animate(index))
```

you need

```
return animations[index]().each("end", function() { animate(index) })
```

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nGtbT/1/)

Comment: Yeah, really close! How the elements in the array are function I did  not think I need a explicit a function in the parameter of the each. Again, thanks!

Comment: @user829971 Happy to help! Why not accept this answer then (or upvote)? It's mah peanuts :)

Comment: Sorry! I cant voye up, I don`t have the enough reputation.

Comment: @Terbiy the OP must have deleted the original jsfiddle, which deleted mine too