# D3.js chain transitions for compound animations for different shapes

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, transition, chained

#### What I'm trying to do...

I'm toying with D3 to make a compound animation. I have the following final state:

[image]

Essentially I want to animation connecting the dots - add the first *circle*. Then draw the *line* to the second circle. Once the line is drawn, the second circle is added.

To add some visual appeal, I perform other transitions, such as changing *circle* radius for the first and second circle as the line is draw.

#### What I've tried...

I can add the circles and draw the line individually, including animations. However, I'm not sure how to proceed with chaining the transitions together to form the compound animation.

I've [read about transitions/animations](http://blog.visual.ly/creating-animations-and-transitions-with-d3-js/), which suggests using `each("end")`. While this would work to draw the initial objects, end doesn't fire until after the other transitions.

#### Questions

- Is using `each("end", ...)` the correct approach for chaining transitions?
- How do I start another animation (i.e. start draw the line) while still allowing another transition to complete (i.e. the first circle radius burst).

Comment: Someone who was trying to do essentially the same thing asked a question here a couple of days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692910/queue-of-transitions-in-d3-js-one-by-one/15693534. I don't know if his approach is the most idiomatic approach, but it does work (but see my reply to his Q for the working jsFiddle link).

Comment: Instead of explicitly chaining the transitions, you can also use the `delay()` function to delay the start of the subsequent animations until the previous ones have finished.

Comment: @meetamit, While close, it's not the same question. I'm still curious how to chain these together. He seems to have a set of animations, not necessarily dependent upon one another.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff, I'll look into that. But keep in mind that some transitions run in parallel. So delay wouldn't necessarily work across the board.

Comment: It should as long as you can determine when each transition should start. If, for example, your line is drawn in 1 second, you would delay the transition drawing the second circle by that amount of time.

Comment: I get an error when attempting to append the line after the circle transition - `object has no method 'append'`. Why don't you leave a quick example as an answer so you can get some points.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The transition are easier to chain since d3.v3 without using "end". See the notes [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/3.0#transitions).

For example, look at [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3943967):

```
rect.transition()
  .duration(500)
  .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 10; })
  .attr("x", function(d, i, j) { return x(d.x) + x.rangeBand() / n * j; })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand() / n)
  .transition()
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); });
```

That's for transitions on the same element. For different elements, look at [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3903818).

```
// First transition the line & label to the new city.
var t0 = svg.transition().duration(750);
t0.selectAll(".line").attr("d", line);
t0.selectAll(".label").attr("transform", transform).text(city);

// Then transition the y-axis.
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[city]; }));
var t1 = t0.transition();
t1.selectAll(".line").attr("d", line);
t1.selectAll(".label").attr("transform", transform);
t1.selectAll(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
```

The transition is attached to the svg element and chained from there.

Comment: bl.ocks.org must have crappy SEO. I searched for *chained transitisions* all afternoon. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You could search on this gallery: http://biovisualize.github.io/d3visualization/#title=Chained Transitions or using Gist search, since a bl.ocks is a Gist viewer

Comment: Wish I could upvote this answer like 42 times.  I appear to have followed exactly in @JasonMcCreary's footsteps.

Comment: Re SEO comments, care: chained **transitions**, not transitisions