# What is the correct way of chaining transitions in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

Inspired by this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794619/d3-js-chain-transitions-for-compound-animations-for-different-shapes), I created an animation ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ded9o8tp/)) that draws a circle, then a line that connects it to another circle. I read that D3 v3 doesn't need to listen the the `end` event to chain transitions.

[image]

The code below works, but how should I refactor it so it doesn't use `end` events?

```
var margin = {top: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40, right: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.bottom - margin.top;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var t0 = svg.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 0)
    .attr("cx", 40)
    .attr("cy", 40)
    .attr("class", "point")
  .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("r", 4);

var t1 = t0.each("end", function(){ 
    var t2 = svg.append("path")
        .style("stroke", "#000")
        .style("stroke-width", 2)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .attr("d", "M40,40L40,40")
      .transition()
        .ease("linear")
        .duration(500)
        .attr("d", "M40,40L80,80");

    t2.each("end", function(){ 
        svg.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 1)
            .attr("cx", 80)
            .attr("cy", 80)
            .attr("class", "point")
          .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr("r", 4);
    });
});
```

Comment: Definitely lose the "end" design pattern. Instead, use selectAll or select on the elements you want to chain upon. Simply one run update followed by another and make the selection again with each update. See: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3903818

Answer (score 2):

Ok, thanks to the comments I realized I can just do this:

- append the first item and create the first transition with `t0 = svg.transition()`,
- append the second item and create the second transition (which will trigger after `t0` ends) `t1 = t0.transition()`
- repeat for the third item `t2 = t1.transition()`

Note that if you want to change the duration of each transition, it must be done when you define it. This is wrong:

```
var t1 = t0.transition()
    .ease("linear");
t1.select("path.line")
    .duration(500)
    .attr("d", "M40,40L80,80");
```

It should be:

```
var t1 = t0.transition()
    .ease("linear");
    .duration(500)
t1.select("path.line")
    .attr("d", "M40,40L80,80");
```

This is the final code ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wk59zkt6/1/)):

```
var margin = {top: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40, right: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.bottom - margin.top;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 0)
    .attr("cx", 40)
    .attr("cy", 40)
    .attr("class", "point-start")

svg.append("path")
    .style("stroke", "#000")
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", "M40,40L40,40");

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 0)
    .attr("cx", 80)
    .attr("cy", 80)
    .attr("class", "point-end")

var t0 = svg.transition()
    .duration(100);

t0.select("circle.point-start")
    .attr("r", 4);

var t1 = t0.transition()
    .duration(500)
    .ease("linear");
t1.select("path.line")
    .attr("d", "M40,40L80,80");

var t2 = t1.transition()
    .duration(100);
t2.select("circle.point-end")
    .attr("r", 4);
```

Comment: Yeah. It's fairly straightforward. End just complicates things.